# Can't receive messages after connection restart in MultiUserChat (XMPP ,Smack)

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I had implemented MultiUserChat in my project using Smack(I am using Openfire server in backend)

Create a new group, invite the user to a group is working fine.
Normal group chat is working fine for the first time.

If any user's connection is restarted then that user can not receive a message from the group (If he/she send a message to group it is received by other users). 
**On connection restart, I had rejoined user to that group. Because of XEP-0045, say's if the user will go offline it will automatically remove from group**

I don't understand why user not receive messages from the group if a connection is a restart. Can you help me